# Sections must only appear once per config file. See the help topic <location> for exceptions.Why?

Tags: asp.net, configuration

> Configuration Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

```
<configuration>

  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="makovetskiyd@yahoo.co.uk">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" enableSsl="true" defaultCredentials="false" port="587" userName="****" password="****"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>

  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
<add name="SqlState" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;DataBase=AnyNameOfServerState;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="YourGuruDB" connectionString="Data Source=DIMA-00AA1DA557;Initial Catalog=model;Integrated Security=True"/>
<add name="modelConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>


  <system.web>

<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="SqlState" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
<compilation debug="true"/>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".MyCookie" loginUrl="~/Registration.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/">
    <credentials passwordFormat="MD5">
      <user name="****" password="****"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="modelConnectionString" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="modelConnectionString" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" enablePasswordReset="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="1000" passwordAttemptWindow="4000" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Encrypted" applicationName="/WebSite10"/>
  </providers>
</membership>

<machineKey validationKey="****" decryptionKey="****" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=****"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=****"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=****"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=****"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: Line 49:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
//I get it there..Thats where it is pointed to

Answer (score 4):

You have two compilation tags

```
<compilation debug="true"/>
```

and

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">   
    <assemblies>     
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>     
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>     
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>     
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>   
    </assemblies> 
</compilation>
```

Comment: As to the "WHY?", it's because the system can't work out which one you intended to use, especially if they specify different settings.

Answer (score 0):

The Error below happen when you have the Compilation element twice in your config file.  Just take one or the other one out.

It seem that there is two  section.

Remove
`<compilation>`

Leave
`<compilation debug="true" >`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem today after installing Ajax toolkit. If you added custom controls before installing ajax toolkit via in web.config as:

```
<pages>
    <controls> 
             <!--Your custom control class information-->      
             <add tagPrefix=".." namespace="..."/>      
    </controls>
 </pages>
```

combine it with ajaxToolkit section after deleting your tags  as :

```
<pages>   
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />    
        <!--Your custom control class information-->
        <add tagPrefix="..." namespace="..." />
      </controls>
</pages>
```