# 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName CevicheOnLineServices.Context.Connection `-`force
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system`enter code here` failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Sections must only appear once per config file.  See the help topic <location> for exceptions. (C:\Development\CevicheOnLineServices\CevicheOnLineServices\tmp5E99.tmp line 52)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_ConnectionStrings()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..ctor()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForAssembly(Assembly assemblyHint, Type contextTypeHint)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForContext(Type contextType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1..ctor()
   at CevicheOnLineServices.Migrations.Configuration..ctor() in C:\Development\CevicheOnLineServices\CevicheOnLineServices\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 10
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.MigrationsConfigurationFinder.FindMigrationsConfiguration(Type contextType, String configurationTypeName, Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at 

    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
    The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception.

// here its my config file

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-CevicheOnLineServices-20170219094640.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-CevicheOnLineServices-20170219094640;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
         <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-ALIUH4AH\;Initial Catalog=CevicheOnLineDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
      -->
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>

      <connectionStrings>
          <add name="Connection" connectionString="Data Source=laptop-aliuh4ah;Initial Catalog=CevicheOnLineDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>


      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
          <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
            <assemblies>     
              <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
              <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
              <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
              <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
              <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
              <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
              <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
              <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
              <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
              <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />   
              <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />

        <httpHandlers>
          <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
          <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <!-- Glimpse: This can be commented in to add additional data to the Trace tab when using WebForms
            <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" enabled="true" pageOutput="false"/> -->
        <httpModules>
          <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
          <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
          <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
          <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
        </httpModules>

        <httpModules>
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
        </httpModules>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
          <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
          <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=7.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider></providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
          <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
          <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
      </system.codedom>
    </configuration>
//
```

please help me spent 2 entire days and i can not see how to fix it 
 i can be contact gerry_otiz@hotmail.com
there is not enough doco to search try all suggestions i can not seemed to  making any progress

Comment: The problem is somewhere in your web.config, you have multiple entries for the same item. Quote "Sections must only appear once per config file."

Answer (score 1):

The `httpModules` element inside `system.web` in `web.config` is certainly duplicated like this:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- other stuff -->

    <httpModules>
        <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>

    <!-- duplicated httpModules here -->
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>

    <!-- other stuff -->
</system.web>
```

I suggest you removing second `httpModules` element which is redundant, hence combining all inner elements into single `httpModules` element:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- other stuff -->

    <httpModules>
        <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>

    <!-- other stuff -->
</system.web>
```

Related issues:

[Sections must only appear once per config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802280/sections-must-only-appear-once-per-config-file)

[Sections must only appear once per config file. See the help topic <location> for exceptions.Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373439/sections-must-only-appear-once-per-config-file-see-the-help-topic-location-fo)